# bcp command is replacing empty strings with nulls

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy, bcp

The following bcp command is auto converting empty strings to nulls:

```
BCP "stored_proc_name" queryout C:\Outdir\data.csv -c -t , -T -Sserverx -Uusery -Ppassz -dproddb
```

I need the empty strings to be retained
and not be replaced by NULLs.

What's the best way to do this?  Can the bcp auto conversion be turned off?

Answer (score 1):

That is by [design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx):

> **out** copies from the database table or view to a file. If you specify an existing file, the file is overwritten. When extracting data, note that the bcp utility represents an empty string as a null and a null string as an empty string.

The workaround is in your stored procedure, when issuing `SELECT`, use `NULLIF()` or `COALESCE()` function to output a `NULL` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to leave null value not empty string on database. Then BCP will export empty string into file (.csv, .txt or so).

Please refer to [BCP MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility):

> - out copies from the database table or view to a file. If you specify an existing file, the file is overwritten. **When extracting data,
>     note that the bcp utility represents an empty string as a null and a
>     null string as an empty string.**

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar BCP script to export data into .csv. I found the easiest (in terms of latter changes if necessary) to create a view from the tables you need with [`COALESCE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or [`ISNULL()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) and `ALTER` your stored procedure to `SELECT` the data from the view.

Comment: ....oops, in your case you may need to use NULLIF(COALESCE(your_data,
   0), 0)) or something like that this would ensure the NULL values